# Disable scroll on one pager

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have built a one pager and am currently fiddling around to disable scrolling on every device if the mobile menu is open.

I'm giving the content wrapper a class of `.no-scrolling` if the hamburger menu button is clicked. This class has the following styles:

```
.no-scrolling {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works well on desktop and mobile (touch) devices, **but** unfortunately, the page jumps to the very top of the page if the class is activated. Well, I do understand, why this happens, but I don't know a workaround.

If the user has scrolled to, let's say, half of the page and then decides to open the menu, the page shouldn't jump to the top but should stay at this exact position.

How would you do this?

---

## Edit

Due to a proposal of **skyline3000**, I added a prevent default. Unfortunately, this code does not work as it's supposed to.
On my iPhone and on my iPad (Pro) it works, but on my MacBook it doesn't...

Anything wrong with it?

```
function animateToggle(click, move) {
  
  $('.hamburger-menu').on(click, function() {

    // some code to add an overlay and animate the button

    if (prevent === true) {
      $('html').unbind(move).on(move, function() {
        prevent = false;
      });
    }
    else {
      $('html').on(move, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        prevent = true;
      });
    }
    var prevent = false;

  });

} // animateToggle()

if ( touchscreen === true ) {
  animateToggle('touchend', 'touchmove');
}
else if ( touchscreen === false ) {
  animateToggle('click', 'mousemove')
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider properly blocking scroll events in JavaScript. document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); return; }, false). You could add and remove this when the menu is opened/closed.

Comment: @skyline3000 I thought, that one can't set back to default a preventDefault?!

Comment: Well, you would create a function to do the preventDefault, then add and remove the event listener as necessary: `function preventDefault(event) {event.preventDefault(); }` ... Then when the menu opens you can do `document.addEventListener('scroll', preventDefault, false);` and when the menu closes ``document.removeEventListener('scroll', preventDefault, false);` See one of my other (somewhat) related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488336/re-enabling-touchmove-eventlistener-iphone-app-with-phone-gap/7490418#7490418

Comment: @skyline3000 Does not work for me. The scrolling is disabled, but I can't manage to enable it. -> Please check the question, I'll post my code in a moment.

Comment: For the second case, I believe you want to block `scroll` rather than `mousemove`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to test without this "position: fixed;"? Because just the "overflow:hidden" is enough to "lock" the page where it is

Comment: It's enough on desktop devices, but unfortunately you can scroll on touch devices :/

Answer (score 0):

Setting position to "fixed" jump to top because you have no top/bottom values set, so by default they are '0'.

To prevent this you should save your scroll offset before set the position and set it as top, for example, in "$(document).click"

```
var ftop = $(window).scrollTop();
$('').css({position: 'fixed', top: ftop + 'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your code

```
.no-scrolling {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to the Window element, not the container on click. I dont think you need the position:fixed.